# 80's movie where tourists are forced to play life and death chess game after being captured and imprisoned

Tags: identify-this-movie

- American movie
- Genre is Drama
- may have watched it on HBO or similar network
- 2 main characters are about college aged(possibly on a college break or holiday)
- one of the characters is more athletic, physical type, daring & outgoing. He is good looking (possibly blonde or light brown hair)
- other character is more subdued, weaker & intellectual type (dark hair)
- I'm thinking the movie is supposed to take place in Russia with the border being crossed from Norway or Finland.

Movie starts out with a scene of a young teenage girl with curly blonde hair picking berries on a side of a mountain with another girl. She's dressed in skirt and shawl. The blonde girl gets separated from the other one & mistakenly crosses the border & is spotted by guards or patrols. She tries to run from them but is caught a dragged away.Then there is a caption that reads  > Every year many people wander over the wrong side of the border and are never seen again

The plot is two young men who are best friends who go on a vacation possibly to Norway or Finland. They are hiking & cross the border into Russia & are  captured & imprisoned. Before this in another scene they are seen taking pictures at a remote border check point. The one character brazenly goes back & forth under the gate to joke around, seemingly to dare the patrol guard to arrest him. After they are taken to prison they are separated & treated cruelly. For a while every thing is only seen from the weaker character's point of view. After a lot of time has passed that one is then taken to an arena of sorts. There he sees a giant chess board where the prisoners are being made to make moves & act like they are the chess pieces. There are spectators and what seems to be rulers that call out the moves. The chess pieces/prisoners must then try to make the moves by battling with the others. He then finds his friend. But the friend doesn't even recognize him because he has been combating for so long (very well) & has been brainwashed like he is in a different reality & only knows the chess game to be real now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [Born American (1986)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091313/). Insanely stupid movie.

> Three American students vacationing in Finland, cross the border into Russia for fun of it. When they are spotted by the Russian soldiers who are shooting to kill, it's not fun anymore. Captured and thrown in jail, they find it's not fun either. It's a nightmare.

Comment: Thanks! I must have only seen the beginning and the end as a kid. Cause I didn't recall most of it.Seemed really cool then. lol!